# Loop through array and append image src attribute for multiple image place holders from an Ajax Success response

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to loop through an array and append the Base64 Data URL to an image src attribute for multiple image place holders (these were dynamically created within an Asp.net Webforms page) from an Ajax Success response.

Here's what I have tried:

```
success: function (response) {
    var getData = JSON.parse(response.d);
    for (var x = 0; x < getData.length; x++) {
        uri = getData[x].ImageURI;
        imageID = getData[x].ID;
        $("[id*=ContentPlaceHolder1_Image",{imageID},"]").attr("src", uri);
    }
},
```

My image place holders look like this:

```
<img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Image236" src="The Base64 URL goes here">
<img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Image237" src="The Base64 URL goes here">
<img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Image238" src="The Base64 URL goes here">
...
```

I'm appending the image ID to this place holder from the response, in addition to setting the `src` attribute. I do not have any errors in the console but the images are not populating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate the strings to create their selector

so either use `+` and strings

```
$("[id*=ContentPlaceHolder1_Image" + imageID + "]").attr("src", uri);
```

or template literals (*note the different quotes and the `$`*)

```
$(`[id*=ContentPlaceHolder1_Image${imageID}]`).attr("src", uri);
```